# Batch extract lists/dataframes from a list

Tags: r, list, loops, batch-file

I'm new to working with lists in R. I'm trying to figure out how to batch extract and create individual data frames from a list. The list I'm trying to work with is heavily nested, with hundreds of parts (for those who might be familiar or interested, I'm working with data from DeepLabCut and code called DLC_Analyzer (https://github.com/ETHZ-INS/DLCAnalyzer).

Example code to show what kind of lists I'm working with and hopefully explain what I'm trying to do

```
#Quick example to show the nature of the lists I'm trying to work with#
library(sp)         #tested with v1.3-2
library(imputeTS)   #tested with v3.0
library(ggplot2)    #tested with v3.1.0
library(ggmap)      #tested with v3.0.0
library(data.table) #tested with v1.12.8
library(cowplot)    #tested with v0.9.4
library(corrplot)   #tested with v0.84
library(keras)      #REQUIRES TENSORFLOW INSTALL. tested with v2.2.5.0

setwd("PathToDLCFolder") #from github link above
source('R/DLCAnalyzer_Functions_final.R')
input_folder <- "example/OFT/DLC_Data/"
files <- list.files(input_folder) 
pipeline <- function(path){
  Tracking <- ReadDLCDataFromCSV(path, fps = 25)
  Tracking <- CutTrackingData(Tracking,start = 100, end = 300)
  Tracking <- CalibrateTrackingData(Tracking, "area",in.metric = 42*42, points = c("tr","tl","bl","br"))
  Tracking <- CleanTrackingData(Tracking, likelihoodcutoff = 0.95)
  Tracking <- AddOFTZones(Tracking, scale_center = 0.5,scale_periphery  = 0.8 ,scale_corners = 0.4)
  Tracking <- OFTAnalysis(Tracking, movement_cutoff = 5, integration_period = 5, points = "bodycentre")
  return(Tracking)
}
TrackingAll <- RunPipeline(files,input_folder,FUN = pipeline) #This creates an example list of what I'm trying to work with.
```

I'd like to be able to pull the data frame associated with the nose tracking data from each of these sub-lists, but in a batch, keeping the name of the csv file. So instead of having to call each individually like:

```
OFT_1 <- TrackingAll$'OFT_1.csv'$data$nose
OFT_2 <- TrackingAll$'OFT_2.csv'$data$nose
OFT_3 <- TrackingAll$'OFT_3.csv'$data$nose
OFT_4 <- TrackingAll$'OFT_4.csv'$data$nose
```

I want to be able to it in a batch (since my actual data consists of 100s of these lists, not just the four in this example).

I've tried searching how to extract data frames from lists, but only found how to do it individually, and most examples don't account for the multiple layers of the lists I'm trying to work with. I'm guessing that the approach would be a for loop, but I'm struggling with how to even start. Help?

Comment: something like `lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, c("data", "nose"))`

Comment: Thanks! I think that starts to help me get at the solution, as it places the data frames I want into their own list. However, I would still think I want to be able to extract those data frames out of the list, without having to call one each individually (see last part of example where I want each "csv" to have its own named dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to accomplish what I wanted:

```r
## Create list of four data frames corresponding to input files
newlist <- lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, c("data", "nose")) 

## Place data frames in global environment (named 'OFT_1.csv', etc.) 
## for use without '$'
list2env(newlist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I realize that the second step is not essential and not practical when the number of files is large, but I found it convenient here.